# kernel32.dll is missing in Windows Phone 8.1 app thru NHunspell

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, kernel32, nhunspell

I'm trying to use NHunspell library in my windows phone app (available thru NuGet package).
In the Hunspell constructor i'm getting this error:
Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'kernel32.dll': The specified module could not be found.

Does anyone know how why it happens and how can i fix it? i'm running my app in the emulator, maybe this cause the issue?

The same code works fine in a simple desktop app, so i guess it is something with the project refrences or stuff like that...

And if there's someone who is familiar with this spellcheck lib and WP or in general, i'll appricaite his help.

Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are not going to be able to use NHunspel on windows phone, it is a .net wrapper for Hunspell which is a native windows component.

Comment: Thanks Ben! so do you have another idea for spell checking API for Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

In fact NHunspell uses Hunspell. Hunspell is not a native windows component as mentioned, it is a C coded spell checker library. If it is possible to use native compiled libraries on Windows Phone, someone could compile Hunspell for it, so that this can be deployed to the Phone. This would also be nice on Android and iOS in conjunction with Xamarin. Currently there is no native Hunspell library for windows phone. But this should be possible with Windows Phone 8 native support.

I have already laid the foundation for this cross platform compilation by separating the NHunspell and native Hunspell projects in the latest NHunspell version. But I'm targeting Linux x86 with this step. If someone is good at cross platform development, maybe this could be done for the mobile devices too.

This blog post describes the new build process where additional native builds can be integrated: [Building NHunspell with PowerShell Build Tools](http://www.crawler-lib.net/powershell-build-tools-nhunspell)