# SpellCheck for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, spell-checking

I'm using `NetSpell.SpellChecker` in my WindowsPhone 8.1 application, but when I compile the code I'm getting the following error:

> The base3 class or interface 'System.CompoenentModer.Compoenent' in
>   assembly xxx referenced by type NetSpell.SpellChecker.Spelling could
>   not be resolved.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it? Is NetSpell supported in Windows Phone apps?
If not, do you have any idea of how to implement spellcheck/auto correct in Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Runtime to build apps for Windows Phone, the support is built in, use:

```
<TextBox IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" />
```

Unfortunatly this doesn't work in Windows Phone Silverlight applications.

And the NetSpell library doesn't seem to be compatible with Windows Phone, it is dependent on `System.ComponentModel.Component`, which according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx) is not supported on Windows Phone. I have yet to find another spell checker library. ([NHunSpell](http://www.crawler-lib.net/nhunspell) also [doesn't seem to work with Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247507/kernel32-dll-is-missing-in-windows-phone-8-1-app-thru-nhunspell))

If it is for your app, I would recommend writing the app as a Windows Phone Store app (Windows Runtime) and use the built in support instead.

Comment: Thanks Johan for your answer! actually, i'm trying to write a general api for spellcheck, so I don't really need the textbox control. is there any way to upload external string to the textbox and get the context menu options? I can't find any event or method for that :(

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do? What you mean by "upload external string to the textbox"?

Comment: what i'm trying to do is to implement a simple service for spellcheck, the interface will look like: public List<string> SpellCheck(string text); the method will get a string a if the word is not spelled correctly it will return a list of optional words. there are various libraries for that but they don't support mobile so as kind of hack I thought using the textbox property...